# Create layer from an array of geometries in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, geometry, features

After a fetch from a `PostgreSQL` view, I get a response and extract the geometries in an array of object `result`.

```
.then(rep => rep.json())
    .then(tableauObjOpe => {
      for (const ope of tableauObjOpe) {
      result.push(new GeoJSON().readGeometry(ope.geom))
      }
```

result in the console :

[image]

From this new array, I would like to create a layer.  What is the simplest solution: define a source then a layer or there is a shorter way?

And I am confused : when configuring a vector source, in my case, it seems I have to use a custom `loader` and avoid `url` param right ?

Using OpenLayers 6.3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need an array of features, not just geometries.  Create features containing the identifying properties of each `ope`, then read the geometry into OpenLayers format and set it in the feature.  Finally create a layer and source with your features array (or you could add them to an existing source)

```
.then(rep => rep.json())
.then(tableauObjOpe => {
  const format = new GeoJSON();
  const features = [];
  for (const ope of tableauObjOpe) {
    const feature = new Feature(ope)
    feature.setGeometry(format.readGeometry(ope.geom))
    features.push(feature);
  }
  map.addLayer(
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new vectorSource({
        features: features
      })
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer.